# Specific R command-line options when running shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny-server

I am running shiny-server on Ubuntu and I need to set different R command line options - specifically `--max-ppsize`. I didn't manage to find how to modify the way shiny-server runs `R`. How to modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to getting this to work is outlined in [1.3.5 R Installation Location](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#r-installation-location) of the Shiny Server config manual. The main idea is to create your own executable named `R` and have it pass command-line arguments you want to the real `R` executable.

**Step 1: Create a new user**

I named mine Bob. Add the following files to Bob's home directory.

**/home/bob/.bash_profile:**

```
export PATH=/home/bob/myR:$PATH
```

**/home/bob/myR/R:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/R --max-ppsize 123456 "$@"
```

Make the second file executable by doing `chmod +x /home/bob/myR/R`.

**Step 2: Configure shiny to run your app as Bob**

In your Shiny config file, add the following:

```
location /testApp {
  run_as bob;
  site_dir /srv/shiny-server/testApp;
  log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
}
```

When running `testApp`, Shiny will first source Bob's `.bash_profile`, which makes `R` point to Bob's version due to `$PATH` precedence. Bob's version simply adds your desired `--max-ppsize` option and passes it to the real `R` executable together with other options `"$@"`. You can test this yourself, by doing:

```
$ su bob
$ source /home/bob/.bash_profile
$ which R
/home/bob/myR/R
$ R -q --args Test
> commandArgs()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R" "--max-ppsize"          "123456"
[4] "-q"                    "--args"                "Test"
```

**Step 3: Create a testApp to make sure everything's running as expected**

Here's my test Shiny app.

**/srv/shiny-server/testApp/ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput( "user" ),
  textOutput( "cmdArgs" )
)
```

**/srv/shiny-server/testApp/server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  output$user <- renderText({
    Sys.info()["user"]
  })

  output$cmdArgs <- renderText({
    paste( commandArgs(), collapse=" " )
  })
}
```

Result in Firefox:

[image]